# How to: Facebook Single Sign On (SSO) on Xamarin.Android apps with Parse?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, xamarin, xamarin.android, parse-platform

Im using Xamarin to build my android app. I'm using Parse as a backend for managing users (including login, sessions, saving user info, etc)

Im trying to do something simple, but can't find any tutorial on it.

I wish to enable users to tap on the 'sign in via facebook' button and given they are logged in to facebook app on their android, my app will automatically sign them in without them entering username or password.

I've read the Parse docs, nothing there about it https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#fbusers

I've tried that method, it requires entering username and password, https://parse.com/questions/xamarin-facebook-loginasync

There are 2 facebook SDKs for xamarin.Android, no idea which one to use https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookandroid and https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebook-sdk

I'm really lost, I can write more info, but can someone guide me to where to start from ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full answer. Single Sign On and all

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebookandroid/true

https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookandroid